# How to monitor/log wireless events including failed authorization attempts?

Tags: logging, monitoring, wifi

Is it possible to log wireless events including failed authorization attempts?

I have two access points and also would like to see, which one is serving which client and see when client is connected to another AP.

Also, my access points are separate devices, so, I would like to monitor this from separate WiFi card on Linux machine.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can track events from access point(s) by checking its logs. Some of the APs support syslog export, so you can direct AP's logs to your local system and use something like `fail2ban` or other log analyzer to catch failed attempts.

Not all APs support exporting logs with syslog.

Edit: It seems to be possible to sniff for the traffic, once you're connected to AP you can sniff all the traffic to/from it: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12596/can-a-hacker-sniff-others-network-data-over-a-wireless-connection

Edit2: I could't capture any of unicast traffic in my home network. So probably it is something hardly possible.

Comment: So it is impossible to debug such WiFi errors like devices loosing network or saying "Authorization error" from time to time? No any chance to know what was happening at the moment?

Comment: I think I am wrong here, so I will edit my reply.

Comment: I think it is very hard to capture someone's traffic while connected to Wireless network. The only device in the network who can have all information about authentication fails and successes is Access Point. You might want to purchase something more advanced if you're really concerned about wifi monitoring.

Comment: What to purchase then? Except Doomsday Machine :)

Comment: Well, I guess any *WRT AP should be able to do so. Or any enterprise grade ones, like those from Cisco, HP, etc. I have hope that Ubiquity's access points are advanced enough to report and monitor.